# How to display a page of a taxonomy term differently from the default view?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I activated the "Taxonomy term" view to customize the time display. I want to display some terms from another differently. How to do this ?

I have cloned my view "Taxonomy term" and applied to it a criterion of filtering by type of content displaying only my "sujet". Then I customized its display.

The problem, when the cloned view is enabled, all terms show a blank page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should check [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi)

> The TVI (Taxonomy Views Integrator) module allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice